# How to copy href / link with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am doing copy a link with tampermonkey beta and am using chrome
so how can i copy a link  in " " symbol i try many other method i failed 
`</li><li class="item" data-id="805" data-url="http://www???/listen/805/aa.mp3" data1-url="http://??/??.mp3" data-url="http://??/song/??/">`

````
// @name         ???/
// @version      0.3.1
// @match        *://???/*
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_download
// @require    https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant        GM_openInTab
// ==/UserScript==

'use strict';
/* global $ */
(function() {
var at1 = $("a:contains('/listen/')");
if (at1.length) {
   GM_openInTab(at1[0].href);
}
})();```
````

Comment: You're trying to access the `href` attribute but in your HTML example that attribute doesn't exist. Try `at1[0].getAttribute("data-url")`, or using jQuery: `at1.eq(0).attr("data-url")`.

Comment: Yes there is no attribute (</li><li class=...)
i try but still not working

Comment: Please post the full HTML. We're shooting in the dark, otherwise.

Comment: https://onlinenotepad.us/J9c3DR67wE 
i hope...

Comment: I don't see any HTML matching what you posted in your example. The closest I see is `<li class="cplayer-sound-item" data-sound-id="1424632" data-sound-url= ... etc`; I'm *guessing* you'll want to use `at1[0].getAttribute("data-sound-url")` as that's what contains the mp3 URL.

Comment: Thanks for the help I found Answer 
` var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("cplayer-sound-item")[0];

   var result = fields.getAttribute("data-sound-url")
alert (result);

//   GM_openInTab(result);`
and i  Learned a lot  Again thanks

Comment: No worries; glad you figured it out. Just FYI your answer doesn't make use of jQuery. If you're including the library in your script, you may as well use it: `$(".cplayer-sound-item").attr("data-sound-url")` will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can start with...

There is no need to use 700+ functions of Jquery for such a small code.

If HTML is like this:

```
</li><li class="item" data-id="805" data-url="http://www..../listen/805/aa.mp3" 
data1-url="http://.../....mp3" data-url2="http://..../song/??/">....</li>
```

Supposing there is only 1 link that you want to open and the `data-url` ends with ".mp3"

```
// @name         Open MP3
// @version      1.0
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        GM_openInTab
// ==/UserScript==


const link = document.querySelector('li[data-url$=".mp3"]');
if (link) {
  GM_openInTab(link.getAttribute('data-url'));
}
```

Comment: erosman Awesome Thats i call Legendary Programmer Thanks a lot
but am just newbie  hehe...